# Comparing two strings, problems with strcmp

Tags: c, strcmp, strcpy

I'm trying to check if the line read from stdin begins with "login:" but strcmp does not seem to work.

```
char s1[20], s2[20];
fgets(s1, 20, stdin);
strncpy(s2,s1,6);
strcmp(s2, "login:");
if( strcmp(s2, "login:") == 0)
    printf("s2 = \"login:\"\n");
else
    printf("s2 != \"login:\"\n");
```

I don't care what comes after "login:", i just want to make sure that's how the command is given. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `strcmp` is for **exact** matches.  I suggest perusing the [C string library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) to see if there's another function you could use for this task...

Comment: I am copying the first 6 characters (which should be "login:") into another string that is going to be compared with the string "login:", so i am going for an exact match.

Comment: Oh that's a fair point; I hadn't noticed that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`strcmp` returns 0 if the two strings are exactly the same to accomplish what you want to do

Use :

`strstr(s2 ,  "login:")`

(It return `NULL` if the string doesn't exist in `s2`)

or

`strncmp(s2 , "login:" , 6)`

This will compare the first 6 characters (if `s2` begins with "login:" , it will return 0)

Answer (score 1):

Every string in C is followed be a null terminator, which shows

when the end of a string occurs.

Right now, you're copying 6 letters from s1 to s2, which is

```
login:
```

this means that you aren't copying the null terminator.

So s2 isn't exactly going to be "login:" as you wanted it to be.

so I suggest rather using

```
strstr(s2, "login:")
```

to check if login: is contained in s2.

Answer (score 0):

```
char s1[20], s2[20];
fgets(s1, 20, stdin);
strncpy(s2,s1,6);
strcmp(s2, "login:");
if( strcmp(s2, "login:") == 0)
    printf("s2 = \"login:\"\n");
else
    printf("s2 != \"login:\"\n");
```

You compare your String with "login" which includes the following characters: 'l''o''g''i''n'':''\0' So if the Strings should be equal there have to be a '\0' in s2. The following Code should work:

```
char s1[20], s2[20];
fgets(s1, 20, stdin);
strncpy(s2,s1,6);
s2[6]='\0'; //end of String
strcmp(s2, "login:");
if( strcmp(s2, "login:") == 0)
    printf("s2 = \"login:\"\n");
else
    printf("s2 != \"login:\"\n")
```

Answer (score -1):

string library `<string.h>` in c contains two functions `strcmp(s1,s2)` and `strcmpi(s1,s2)`.
`strcmp` function can not compare strings by length.
it compares ascii values of first character of string and if i m providing `s1="Login"` and `s2="Sign out"` then it returns negative value because ascii of 'L' is less than ascii of 'S'.
if first characters are same than it goes for checking 2nd.